# how to make a dotted point rotation around the border of a rectangular container

Tags: html, css, reactjs, animation

Animation on the border of a  **Rectangle** :-

I need a rectangle text box with border and on its border. I want to make an animation in which a small tiny  rounded ball is start rotating along the border of rectangle when we hover on the rectangle

Comment: Please show us the code you have already - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with doing that. Also could you explain more what 'rotating along the border' means. Is it the same as 'moving along the border' or is there some rotation of the ball itself also to take place?

Comment: sir i need a full width rectangle , like a bootstrap container , and on its border the ball is rotating . please solve my question

Comment: sir please put the width of a rectangle is auto /Or  100%

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this, by styling the `before` pseudo element as rounded ball and providing animation by changing it's `left` and `top` properties relative to `box` element i.e. element.

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 2em auto;
}

.box::before {
  content: "";
  background-color: red;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  top: 2em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-100%, -100%);
}

.box:hover::before {
  animation: moveBall 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes moveBall {
  0% {
    left: calc(50% - 50px);
    top: 2em;
  }
  25% {
    left: calc(50% + 70px);
    top: 2em;
  }
  50% {
    left: calc(50% + 70px);
    top: calc(2em + 120px);
  }
  75% {
    left: calc(50% - 50px);
    top: calc(2em + 120px);
  }
  100% {
    left: calc(50% - 50px);
    top: calc(2em);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```